# MooTools Drag/Slider not operating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, mootools

I created this JSbin, since I will need this nice slider for something I am creating. The bin can be found here http://jsbin.com/ipoloy/3/edit

Since this is my very FIRST time using MooTools not I'm quite sure how to write it, I copied what the documentation said just to see how it works first. Well it didn't, so then I wrapped it in a `$(function() { });` still nothing. Do I need to add the jQuery 1.9 plus MooTools 1.4.5?

Any one with good information, please let me know so I can figure this out and get going on this slider.

Comment: you dont need to add jQuery to mootools to make the slide work, you do need the mootools more http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Slider

Comment: @DavidChase I got the slider from there, but like I said it didn't work. As I do understand what you are saying, but is "more" an addition? I add mootools to the JSBIN, so is that not all that is needed?

Comment: check my answer with the jsbin, more tools is additional similar to jquery ui for jquery all you need to is add that `.js` file and it would work again check my jsbin edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add mootools more and along with the mootools and it will work.

http://jsbin.com/egicem/1/edit

Add this below the mootools library:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools-more/1.4.0.1/mootools-more-yui-compressed.js"></script>
```

its hosted on http://cdnjs.com/ website

Comment: Thanks @DavidChase you've been much help! I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok I am getting one issue- Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement' ?? Why is this I copied exactly what you had except the changing of the text I am changing the borderRadius...

Comment: Ok it is sloppy right now lol I will though... http://jsbin.com/aloqez/1/edit   I placed it all within the HTML section since I have it all like that specifically in my doc. (We can only right HTML page not separate files)

Comment: Ok so I got rid of the getElement function and tweeked the code around after reading more into the Docs of the MooTools Slider/more. It is now working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add mootools more (Slider is in mootools more):

but I don't think "more" is in google apis so you need to build it in mootools site: http://mootools.net/more/

http://jsfiddle.net/rjAN3/

```
var slider = $('slider');

  new Slider(slider, slider.getElement('.knob'), {
    range: [9, 35],
    initialStep: 14,
    onChange: function(value){
      if (value) $('fontSize').setStyle('font-size', value);

         }
  });
```

Comment: it does exist in cdnjs: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools-more/1.4.0.1/mootools-more-yui-compressed.js

Comment: ok sorry to sound like a newb guys, but how do I "build" mootools more and what is it exactly? Is it like jQuerys UI?

Comment: @EasyBB yes its like jQuery UI the above cdjns contains all of the available tools need to use anything in the more section on mootools.net